# SQL Server - should I put all my date dimension fields into my fact table if using CCI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, columnstore

We are using SQL Server 2017. Have created (back in v2016) some clustered columnstore index (CCI) fact tables for BI in tools like Power BI. It has awesome performance. Now need more date analytics. A colleague asked if when using CCI if it makes more sense to put all the typical date dimension fields directly in the CCI fact table - both from a storage and from a performance standpoint. I plan on doing some performance tests, but wanting to hear what others have found.

Comment: I dont know about CCI but we used to use ssas for this kind of stuff in my prev workplace and use powerbi on top of ssas

Comment: As opposed to what alternative -- having a time dimension table that you link to with an FK instead? The CCI means you can all but dispense with many dimension tables, because the column partitions basically form dimensions on their own already. There are [good reasons](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/197151/97345) why you might still want a dimension table, but those mostly don't apply to the fields of a typical time dimension. You should still always test, but I expect you'll find that folding the fields into the CCI will give you faster aggregates for only a small storage increase.

Comment: That was my assumption - that CCI would "give you faster aggregates for only a small storage increase". But, for any calc that requires all dates present (like average value over a month, I would still need to join with a date table that has all dates.

Comment: Actually, all you really need is a numbers table (you can even do it with a CTE, but that's usually not as efficient), which is good for many other scenarios as well. You can outer join on it or, if that's not efficient enough, `SUM` over a `UNION ALL` with rows that have zero for your aggregate. I maintain a warehouse where it would be unthinkable for any day not to have data (indeed, it's an error condition if the import detects this), so it's simply not an issue there.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the "sum over a union all..." approach. Could you elaborate?

Comment: `SELECT date, SUM(column) FROM (SELECT date, SUM(column) FROM MyTable GROUP BY date UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(day, n, @startdate), 0 FROM nums WHERE n BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate) - 1) _ GROUP BY date`. Basically, create a virtual result that has zeroes for all your data points and append it, so all data points have data. This generalizes to any kind of range. You can also `LEFT JOIN`, I just prefer `UNION`. I have a slight if unproven suspicion that `UNION` will remain fast even if the virtual table is large, while the join may not.

Comment: And the number table 'nums' just has to be big enough to cover the date ranges/differences of interest?